# JMeter - Execute SSH Commands in parallel

Tags: ssh, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to simulate the below:

```
1. SSH (only once)
2. Execute a command on all the rows in a csv file at once.
```

Number of rows in the csv file is dynamic. If 10, the command needs to be executed over all the 10 rows in parallel.

Am not sure of using SSH Command Sampler here. SSH and Command are to be entered in the same sampler. How do I separate these? i.e. SSH only once and then executing the commands in parallel. Which JMeter components do I use here?

Note: Increasing the number of Threads is not an efficient option. While doing this many sessions get created. In turn hanging the terminal. This option works fine up to 10 users. Not sure if there's a limit on the number of sessions.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that `Increasing the number of Threads is not an efficient option`?

I would suggest moving the `SSH (only once)` to [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) and put  `Execute a command on all the rows in a csv file at once.` bit under the normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

If the number of rows in the CSV file is dynamic - you can make the number of threads dynamic as well using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().size,)}
```

[image]

If you want to execute all the 10 requests (or whatever is the number of lines) at exactly the same moment you can add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)